# Is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-3)^k(k!)}{k^k}$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The question is :

Is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-3)^k(k!)}{k^k}$ convergent?

Note : I can't find the limit of its main term. I know the answer must be related to some test about convergence of series ... I don't know which one and i can't find the limit.

Comment: Ratio test.. ${}$

Comment: @OpenBall that's the problem ! which one is bigger? the denominator or the other one ?

Comment: Same question, replacing `3` with `e`: what's the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the ratio test:

$$\lim_{\text{k}\to\infty}\left|\frac{\left(\frac{\left(-\text{n}\right)^{\text{k}+1}\cdot\left(\left(\text{k}+1\right)!\right)}{\left(\text{k}+1\right)^{\text{k}+1}}\right)}{\left(\frac{\left(-\text{n}\right)^\text{k}\cdot\left(\text{k}!\right)}{\text{k}^\text{k}}\right)}\right|=\lim_{\text{k}\to\infty}\left|-\text{n}\left(\frac{\text{k}}{1+\text{k}}\right)^\text{k}\right|=\left|\text{n}\right|\lim_{\text{k}\to\infty}\left|\left(\frac{\text{k}}{1+\text{k}}\right)^\text{k}\right|=\frac{\left|\text{n}\right|}{e}>1$$

Which leads to:

$$\left|\text{n}\right|>e$$

Comment: Where is $n$ coming from? I can't see an answer from 5xum.

Comment: @LeBtz He was giving the hint: Ratio test, I did that for a general $\text{n}$.

Comment: I find this answer confusing. The answer by @5xum has now been deleted. And all that was mentioned was the ratio test. Including this $n$ is a bit weird.

Answer (score 2):

Apply [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation)
$$k!\sim \sqrt{2k\pi}\left(\frac{k}{e}\right)^k$$
and use [Root Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test).

Comment: But the series is alternating...

Comment: $$L=\text{lim}\,\text{sup}_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{ |a_n|}$$